# What does this symbol $\wedge$ mean in this context?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I am reading real analysis book and encountered this symbol $\wedge$ and $\vee.$

The author says following:

1. $f\wedge g=\frac{1}{2}(f+g-
   |f-g|)$,
2. $f\vee g=\frac{1}{2}(f+g+|f-g|)$.

What are the meanings of  $\wedge$ and $\vee$? For example, I want to know what $f\wedge g$ means like $f^{+}$ means the positive part of the function.

Edit: he also asserts that $\chi_{A\cap B}=\chi_A\wedge \chi_B$ and $\chi_{A\cup B}=\chi_A\vee\chi_B.$

Comment: Minimum and maximum

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: @Jack Principles of Real Analysis by Aliprantis and Burkinshaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be functions with domain $X\subseteq \mathbb R$.

Define a new function $h=f\wedge g$ by $h(x)=\frac12(f(x)+g(x)-|f(x)-g(x)|)$ for all $x\in X$.

At each $x$, $h(x)$ is the minimum of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$,

because if $f(x)\ge g(x)$ then $|f(x)-g(x)|=f(x)-g(x),$

so $h(x)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x)+g(x)-(f(x)-g(x)))=g(x)$,

whereas for $x$ such that $f(x)\lt g(x),\;$   $|f(x)-g(x)|=g(x)-f(x),$

so $h(x)=\frac12(f(x)+g(x)-(g(x)-f(x)))=f(x)$.

A similar argument shows that $f\vee g$ is the maximum of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: This would be my favourite answer if you were to be explicit about the pointwise order, because otherwise it isn't _that_ useful.

Comment: @GitGud:  I edited my answer.  Does it now have what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

The notation $a\wedge b$ stands for $\min\{a,b\}$ and the notation $a\vee b$ stands for $\max\{a,b\}$.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been noted, $\land$ is used to indicate the minimum of $x,\,y$, and $\lor$ their maximum. [More generally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet), the infimum of a set $S$ is denoted $\land S$ and called the *meet* of $S$, while the supremum of $S$ is denoted $\lor S$ and called the *join* of $S$.

The symbols $\land,\,\lor$ are also used in propositional calculus to denote *and* and *(inclusive) or*. (The indicator function relations in your edit use these meanings for the operators.) If we impose the ordering False $\lt$ True on propositions, $p\land q$ returns the minimum of $p,\,q$ in this sense, and $p\lor q$ their maximum. The theory of [semilattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice) is relevant here.

In LaTeX, you chose to denote the meet symbol as `\wedge`, but `\land` would have worked too. The reason this symbol can be called two ways is because it's also used for wedge products in [exterior algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra). I'm not aware of any meaning for $\lor$ in [interior algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_algebra), except in their [modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_algebra#Modal_logic).